# Curve fit with an list of point

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

One of my python script gives me some results depending on processing duration, which I display like that:

[image]

Now I would like to trace the function's curve which approximate the best the results evolution.

After few researches, the best tool I found is the *curve_fit* of *scipy.optimize*.
There is just one problem, the function *curve_fit* requires at first parameter a function (if I have well understand the documentation's example) but my points on the graph are not the results of a function, so I don't know what to put here.

Can someone help me to fix this problem or proposing me another way t do that?

Thanks.

Comment: It is your responsibility to find a suitable function.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "now I would like to trace the function's curve which approximate the best the results evolution", you must have some sort of curve in mind that is the ideal form for the data.  So, what is that function?  In curve-fitting, that function is called "the model function" -- the function that models your data.

Think of it this way: you have 50 or so measurement points. You might believe that they are each perfectly accurate and free-of-error.  But since you asked about curve-fitting, this is probably not the case.  That is, you probably believe there is some noise or errors in the data and that the data can be represented by an idealized function with many fewer than 50 or so parameters (I'd guess 4 or so).

That idealized function that explains your model (and would allow predicting "optimum" values at "duration" points that you did not measure) is the "model function".  If you have that, curve-fitting can help:  you write that function (which probably depends on a few Parameters) to model the data in python and find the best values for the Parameters so that the model matches your data.  If you don't have that, what do you mean by "curve-fitting"?

You could draw a spline through the data or otherwise smooth the data, but that gives little power about predicting new values that would be different from "interpolate/extrapolate the data without worrying about the effect of noise".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an *"exponential approach"* type of curve like you get for charging a capacitor - see [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html).

So, I'd start with this formula:

```
y = a * ( 1 - n * np.exp(-b*x))
```

If I plot that with Matplotlib:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make 100 samples along x-axis, from 0..10
x = np.linspace(0,10,100)

# Make an exponential approach type of curve
a = 17000
n = 1
b = 3
y = a * ( 1 - n * np.exp(-b*x))

# Plot it
plt.title(f'Plot for a={a}, n={n}, b={b}')
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]